# Using specific value in place of parameter type?

Tags: typescript

Looking at the Typescript documentation, I see an example in the declaration merging section that looks something like

```
interface Document {
  createElement(tagName: any): Element;
}
interface Document {
  createElement(tagName: "div"): HTMLDivElement;
  createElement(tagName: "span"): HTMLSpanElement;
}
interface Document {
  createElement(tagName: string): HTMLElement;
  createElement(tagName: "canvas"): HTMLCanvasElement;
}
```

I'm familiar with overloading- but I can't recall ever seeing specific values being used like this in any language I've used.

The default assumption I went with is that overloading gets turned into a switch case or several if statements that check for matching signatures. Based on that assumption- I'd guess that specific values work the same way type would. The method simply checks for a matching types/values in the order the overloads appear in the interface. This would imply that the order of the overloads matters as well.

Is this correct? Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. As a demonstration: open [this TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJRa5W) and position your cursor at the end of line 14, then insert an open parenthesis character `(` to activate the IntelliSense suggestion box. It shows me the cyclable overloads in the following param order: `"div"`, `"span"`, `"canvas"`, `string`, `any`. It appears that the order of definition is unrelated to the order of suggestion. Perhaps someone else will comment with a link to the source code showing authoritative evidence of how overload determinism works.

Comment: Yes, the order matters